# MVC java random number displaying on textfield

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm a C.S.S.E. undergrad student and I'm facing some issues in Java MVC design related to a student program management application. I have to display some auto-generated (random number I guess) on the student ID textfield.

The StudentAddView.java do not display and return the random number on the TextField.

```
public class StudentAddView extends View{

  private JTextField studentNumberField = new JTextField("", SIZE);
  }

  public StudentAddView(Model StudentList, Controller StudentController){

    super(StudentList,StudentController);

    add(studentNumberField);
  }
```

Then for the student.java under model, it contains the methods.

```
public class Student{
  public int studentNumber;
```

the constructor under student.java

```
public void setstudentNumber(int studentNumber)//setter {

  Random random = new Random();

  studentNumber = random.nextInt(1000);

  this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
}

public int getstudentNumber()//getter{

  return studentNumber;}
```

Lastly, the stringbuffer inside the student.java

```
public String StringBuffer (String str){

  str = "student[";

  str = str+"student number"= +studentNumber+","; }
```

or is it because I have to create a class to return the random number and store as a data to return the value inside a textfield?

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to update your registered view(s) after changing a value in the model, i advise you to use a model observer and interfaces as it will make things clearer for real cases in the future.
I strongly advise you to read some example of application of this pattern before trying to use it. It will make it way easier to implement and visualize its purpose and pros. However i won't do it here, as smarter and better people have already done it elsewhere, just google it. (here is a practical example for starters https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm)

Good luck in the great world of patterns !

Comment: sorry, do i need to create a class for updating the view?

Comment: No you don't need to make a class, it could just be a method notifying the observers that the model changed, which will lead the observer to get the new value from the model. Do you understand ?
Here is a great explanation with an UML design http://ima.udg.edu/~sellares/EINF-ES1/MVC-Toni.pdf